# Implementing Indexer in F#

Tags: f#, matrix, indexer

I am trying to convert this C# code to F#:

```
double[,] matrix;

public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.matrix = new double[rows, cols];
    }

 public double this[int row, int col]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.matrix[row, col];
        }
        set
        {
            this.matrix[row, col] = value;
        }
    }
```

Basically my biggest problem is creating the indexer in F#.  I couldn't find anything that I could apply in this situation anywhere on the web.  I included a couple of other parts of the class in case incorporating the indexer into a Matrix type isn't obvious.  So a good answer would include how to make a complete type out of the three pieces here, plus anything else that may be needed.  Also, I am aware of the matrix type in the F# powerpack, however I am trying to learn F# by converting C# projects I understand into F#.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 15, accepted):

F# calls them "indexed properties"; [here is the MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) In F# they work slightly differently - each indexed property has a name.

However, there is a default one called "Item". So an implementation of your example would look like this:

```
member this.Item
  with get(x,y) = matrix.[(x,y)]
  and  set(x,y) value = matrix.[(x,y)] <- value
```

Then this is accessed via `instance.[0,0]`. If you have named it something other than "Item", you would access it with `instance.Something[0,0]`.

Comment: You definitely solved the hardest part of my question, so I'll mark it an an answer.  But please feel free to create the whole type Matrix from what I have given above if you like.  I'm going to go try and figure that part out on my own, but others might appreciate it for future reference.  Thanks for such a quick answer!

Comment: @Beaker : You haven't posted a whole type above, just a constructor and index property.

Comment: For anyone interested I asked a question that further expands on this question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206911/using-f-indexed-properties-in-a-type

Comment: MS's index properties page wasn't clear enough.  This answer cleared it up.  I like the nice clean way #F handles the indexing.  Implementing two dimensional indexing (on a flat array) in C++ is complicated.