# Using F# Indexed Properties in a Type

Tags: f#, types, indexed-properties

I'm trying to convert the following C# into F#:

```
    public class Matrix
    {
       double[,] matrix;

public int Cols
        {
            get
            {
                return this.matrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
            }
        }

public int Rows
        {
            get
            {
                return this.matrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            }
        }

       public Matrix(double[,] sourceMatrix)
       {
        this.matrix = new double[sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1];
        for (int r = 0; r < this.Rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.Cols; c++)
            {
                this[r, c] = sourceMatrix[r, c];
            }
        }
       }

       public double this[int row, int col]
       {
         get
         {
             return this.matrix[row, col];
         }
         set
         {
             this.matrix[row, col] = value;
         }
       }
     }
```

This is what I have so far:

```
type Matrix(sourceMatrix:double[,]) =
let mutable (matrix:double[,]) = Array2D.create (sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) (sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1) 0.0
member this.Item
    with get(x, y) = matrix.[(x, y)]
    and set(x, y) value = matrix.[(x, y)] <- value
do
    for i = 0 to matrix.[i].Length - 1 do
    for j = (i + 1) to matrix.[j].Length - 1 do
        this.[i].[j] = matrix.[i].[j]
```

My type above seems to have two problems I'm not sure how to resolve.  The first one is that matrix.[(x, y)] is expected to have type `a[] but has type double[,].  The second is type definitions must have let/do bindings preceding member and interface definitions.  The problem with that is I'm trying to populate an indexed property in the do block, which means I have to create it first.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, you want to use `matrix.[x,y]` instead of `matrix.[(x,y)]` - your matrix is indexed by two integers, not by a tuple of integers (although these are conceptually similar).

Here's something roughly equivalent to your C#:

```
type Matrix(sourceMatrix:double[,]) =
  let rows = sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1
  let cols = sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1
  let matrix = Array2D.zeroCreate<double> rows cols
  do
    for i in 0 .. rows - 1 do
    for j in 0 .. cols - 1 do
      matrix.[i,j] <- sourceMatrix.[i,j]
  member this.Rows = rows
  member this.Cols = cols
  member this.Item
    with get(x, y) = matrix.[x, y]
     and set(x, y) value = matrix.[x, y] <- value
```

This assumes that your matrix can't actually be reassigned (e.g. in the C# you've posted, you could have made your `matrix` field `readonly` - unless there's additional code that you've hidden).  Therefore, the number of rows and columns can be calculated once in the constructor since the entries of the matrix may change but its size won't.

However, if you want a more literal translation of your code, you can give your newly constructed instance a name (`this` in this case):

```
type Matrix(sourceMatrix:double[,]) as this =
  let mutable matrix = Array2D.zeroCreate<double> (sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) (sourceMatrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)
  do
    for i in 0 .. this.Rows - 1 do
    for j in 0 .. this.Cols - 1 do
      this.[i,j] <- sourceMatrix.[i,j]
  member this.Rows = matrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1
  member this.Cols = matrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1
  member this.Item
    with get(x, y) = matrix.[x, y]
     and set(x, y) value = matrix.[x, y] <- value
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and good catch on the readonly which was a correct assumption on your part.  The original C# wasn't mine and I overlooked that.  Must be nice to be good at both C# and F#.  :)

Comment: I added a follow-up question to this one if anyone is interested:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212570/adding-overloaded-constructors-to-implicit-f-type

Answer (score 2):

```
type Matrix(sourceMatrix:double[,]) =
    let matrix = Array2D.copy sourceMatrix
    member this.Item
        with get(x, y) = matrix.[x, y]
        and set(x, y) value = matrix.[x, y] <- value
```